# using Google Maps API and J2ME?

Tags: google-maps, java-me

Using Eclipse, how can I integrate my J2ME app with Google Maps API?

Can you recommend any articles or tutorials that are helpful, or helped you before?

Comment: You want to display the map on a canvas? What interactivity do you want with the map?

Comment: i just want to display current location "Where i am?".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice article on how to do the integration, but they also have a warning that you should buy an enterprise key for Google Maps.

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Google_Maps_API_in_Java_ME

Comment: Nice answer, but this is the first answer when googling for "google maps java me" -- come on people!